# Is there a way to automatically add manager methods or class level methods to admin page in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-managers

Let's say I have a class Person, which has bunch of manager methods and class level methods. I have the Person enabled in the admin page, but I am trying to find a way so that all these manager/class level methods automatically show on the admin page too.

```
class PersonManager(models.Manager):

    def get_status(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # code to get the status of selected persons


class Person(models.Model):
    objects = PersonManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def email_person(self, email):
        #code to email the specific person
```

So for example, the email_person method would show up when I goto the detailed view on the admin page after selecting an instance. Or one of the manager methods can be invoked in the page of the admin that lists all the instances and I can select which instances I want the manager method to run on. Is there any way like that? I found an article that manually shows how to do so, but I was wondering if there is an existing solution/app that does that by default? http://patrick.arminio.info/additional-admin-views/

Answer (score 0):

You can add [admin actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) to the list view by specifying them in your `ModelAdmin`:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['some_action']

    def some_action(self, queryset, request):
        queryset.some_action()
    some_action.short_description = "Do some action on selected persons"
```

Adding it to the detail view requires more work, but I've found that this method is generally sufficient.